# Inserting data to audit field like created date for test class

Tags: unit-test, datetime, fields, field-update

I am creating a test class and the scenario I am testing requires an older date for the created date. I know CreatedDate is an audit field and I can't write to it. Is there a workaround I could use for writing my test class?

Thanks.

Comment: Kenn, I have not found any workaround for this. Audit fields are available to write only at the time of initial data import that too after contacting Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can write CreatedDate field as it comes under System Audit Field.

Comment: Hi Davendra,

I was looking for a working around tips or tricks in situations where u have to have an older date for created date in a unit test. Audit fields can't be written to for sure unless salesforce is contacted.